# The concept of branch (taken, not taken, diverged) in CUDA

Tags: cuda, branch, nsight

In Nsight Visual Studio, we will have a graph to present the statistics of "taken", "not taken" and "diverged" branches. I am confused about the differece between "not taken" and "diverged".
For example

```
kernel()
{
  if(tid % 32 != 31)
     {...}
  else
     {...}
}
```

In my opinion, when `tid %31 == 31` in a warp, the divergency will happen, but what is "not taken"?

Answer (score 5):

From the Nsight Visual Studio Edition User Guide:

> **Not Taken / Taken Total**: number of executed branch instructions with a uniform control flow decision; that is all active threads of a warp either take or not take the branch.
>
> **Diverged**: Total number of executed branch instruction for which the conditional resulted in different outcomes across the threads of the warp. All code paths with at least one participating thread get executed sequentially. Lower numbers are better, however, check the Flow Control Efficiency to understand the impact of control flow on the device utilization.

Now, let us consider the following simple code, which perhaps is what you are currently considering in your tests:

```
#include<thrust\device_vector.h>

__global__ void test_divergence(int* d_output) {

    int tid = threadIdx.x;

    if(tid % 32 != 31)
        d_output[tid] = tid;
    else
        d_output[tid] = 30000;

}

void main() {

    const int N = 32;

    thrust::device_vector<int> d_vec(N,0);

    test_divergence<<<2,32>>>(thrust::raw_pointer_cast(d_vec.data()));

}
```

The *Branch Statistics* graph produced by Nsight is reported below. As you can see, **Taken** is equal to `100%`, since all the threads bump into the `if` statement. The surprising result is that you have no **Diverge**. This can be explained by taking a look at the disassembled code of the kernel function (compiled for a compute capability of 2.1):

```
MOV R1, c[0x1][0x100];
S2R R0, SR_TID.X;                      
SHR R2, R0, 0x1f;                      
IMAD.U32.U32.HI R2, R2, 0x20, R0;      
LOP.AND R2, R2, -0x20;
ISUB R2, R0, R2;
ISETP.EQ.AND P0, PT, R2, 0x1f, PT;
ISCADD R2, R0, c[0x0][0x20], 0x2;
SEL R0, R0, 0x7530, !P0;
ST [R2], R0;
EXIT;
```

As you can see, the compiler is able to optimize the diassembled code so that no branching is present, except the *uniform* one due to the `EXIT` instruction, as pointed out by Greg Smith in the comment below.

[image]

**EDIT: A MORE COMPLEX EXAMPLE FOLLOWING GREG SMITH'S COMMENT**

I'm now considering the following more complex example

```
/**************************/
/* TEST DIVERGENCE KERNEL */
/**************************/
__global__ void testDivergence(float *a, float *b)
{
    int tid = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
    if (tid < 16) a[tid] = tid + 1;
    else b[tid] = tid + 2;
}

/********/
/* MAIN */
/********/
void main() {

    const int N = 64;

    float* d_a; cudaMalloc((void**)&d_a,N*sizeof(float));
    float* d_b; cudaMalloc((void**)&d_b,N*sizeof(float));

    testDivergence<<<2,32>>>(d_a, d_b);

}
```

This is the *Branch Statistics* graph

[image]

while this is the disassembled code

```
           MOV R1, c[0x1][0x100];                   
           S2R R0, SR_CTAID.X;                         R0 = blockIdx.x
           S2R R2, SR_TID.X;                           R0 = threadIdx.x
           IMAD R0, R0, c[0x0][0x8], R2;               R0 = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x
           ISETP.LT.AND P0, PT, R0, 0x10, PT;          Checks if R0 < 16 and puts the result in predicate register P0
/*0028*/   @P0 BRA.U 0x58;                                 If P0 = true, jumps to line 58
          @!P0 IADD R2, R0, 0x2;                           If P0 = false, R2 = R0 + 2
          @!P0 ISCADD R0, R0, c[0x0][0x24], 0x2;           If P0 = false, calculates address to store b[tid] in global memory
          @!P0 I2F.F32.S32 R2, R2;                                                "
          @!P0 ST [R0], R2;                                                       "
/*0050*/  @!P0 BRA.U 0x78;                                 If P0 = false, jumps to line 78
/*0058*/   @P0 IADD R2, R0, 0x1;                           R2 = R0 + 1
           @P0 ISCADD R0, R0, c[0x0][0x20], 0x2;
           @P0 I2F.F32.S32 R2, R2;
           @P0 ST [R0], R2;
/*0078*/       EXIT;
```

As it can be seen, now we have two `BRA` instructions in the disassembled code. From the graph above, each warp bumps into `3` branches (one for the `EXIT` and the two `BRA`s). Both warps have `1` *taken* branch, since all the threads uniformly bump into the `EXIT` instruction. The first warp has `2` *not taken* branches, since the two `BRA`s paths are not followed uniformly across the warp threads. The second warp has `1` *not taken* branch and `1` *taken* branch since all the warp threads follow uniformly one of the two `BRA`s. I would say that again diverged* is equal to zero because the instructions in the two branches are *exactly* the same, although performed on different operands.

Comment: This answer does a good job explaining the concepts; however, the sample is so simple that the copiler uses SEL with a predicate flag which is a special case of predication. It would be useful in the sample was sufficiently complex that the compiler had to use  but the sample shows predication and not a branch. The answer should explain predication, it would be useful if the answer had an example that generated a BRA, BRX, JCAL, JMP, or JMX instruction. In the above example the branch is from the EXIT instruction.

Comment: Thanks bro,Maybe I need a more complex example to prove that.I will try it by Myself.

Comment: @GregSmith Thanks for your comment. I have tried to provide a more complex example.

Comment: @user2968731 I have provided a more complex example. I hope it will be useful to you.

Comment: As with the second warp, when bumping into the first BRA, all 32 threads will execute the next instruction due to P0=false. On the other hand, when bumping into the second BRA, all 32 thread will jump to EXIT. It seems that all threads in the second warp have uniform control flow decision. So, from my perspective, all thread branch instructions are "taken". Is it necessary for a branch to be true or false if this branch would be considered "taken"?

Comment: I found some reference from wiki: "Jumps typically have unconditional forms where the latter may be katen or not taken (the PC is modifed or not) depending on some condition". Does that mean if one branch is "taken" for a warp, then all threads within the warp would modify their PC when bemping into branch? So, for the second warp in your answer, the "not taken" BRA is the line 0028 due to not modifying the PC?